# Text-overflow on <mat-table> using display-flex Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I use Angular-Material `mat-table Flex` and I would like the extra content not to be displayed like this.

**That's what I have:**
[image]

**And what I want:**
[image]

I tried to use `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but it did not work if someone had an idea, I'm interested.

[**StackBlitz HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-overflow-on-mat-table-using-display-flex?file=app/table-basic-flex-example.html)

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could put the text inside of a `span` element:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxFlex="50">
  <span class="ellipsis">{{element.weight}}</span>
</mat-cell>
```

and apply the `text-overflow` styling on that element:

```
mat-cell > span.ellipsis {
   text-overflow: ellipsis; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-overflow-on-mat-table-using-display-flex-vz5wh7?file=app/table-basic-flex-example.html) for a demo.